# Stash/unstash causing failure java.io.IOException: Failed to extract MyWar.tar.gz

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to stash one file from one machine and unstash it to other machine hence I've following pipeline code -

```
  post {
    success {
        script {
            stash allowEmpty: true, includes: 'Installer/My.war', name: 'MyWar', useDefaultExcludes: false
        }
        node(SERVER1) {
            ws("workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout") {
                script {
                    sh '''mkdir -p "Installer"'''
                    dir('/Installer') {
                        unstash 'MyWar'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this stash code is executed on one machine and unstash on another machine.

But it results into following error -

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to extract MyWar.tar.gz
    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2608)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$500(FilePath.java:211)
    at hudson.FilePath$UntarRemote.invoke(FilePath.java:585)
    at hudson.FilePath$UntarRemote.invoke(FilePath.java:576)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3069)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to 192.168.136.30
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1069)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
        at hudson.FilePath.untar(FilePath.java:571)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.StashManager.unstash(StashManager.java:165)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.stash.UnstashStep$Execution.run(UnstashStep.java:76)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.stash.UnstashStep$Execution.run(UnstashStep.java:63)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Installer
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3256)
    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2592)
    ... 12 more
```

What has gone wrong here?

Comment: Try specifying `dir('/Absolute/path/to/Remote/Root/Agent/Directory/Installer')` based on 'Remote root directory' specified during agent configuration as it seems permission issue from exception stacktrace

Comment: Or just try with `dir('Installer')` by removing trailing '/' to point to relative dir under checked out workspace with 'ws'

Answer (score 0):

As @vinWin suggests, your problem seems to be related to accessing the `Installer` directory.

While on the pipeline you are creating a directory at `workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout/Installer`, on the `dir` command you are trying to access a different one `/Installer`

On one hand, where you trying to refer to `$WORKSPACE` on SERVER1 ? If so, on the `ws` command you should use `$WORKSPACE/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout`. Otherwise, your will be working at `$WORKSPACE/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout`

For the `dir` command, since you are already located at the root of the above defined workspace, using `Installer`, without the leading `/` will suffice.